# C++: make full copy of vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm working on a C++ game. My level objects are in a vector (Object being a superclass for my level's objects).

I need the state of this vector to be saved at checkpoints, and retrieved at death.

So at the beginning of the level, the vector (objects) is created (old_objects).

If you hit a checkpoint, old_objects is erased and objects is re-copied to old_objects.

If you die, the data from objects is erased and old_objects is copied back to objects.

I've been trying to do this several ways but I'm not able to get it working. Help?

EDIT: I tried using a virtual clone() method. It throws out of range errors.

```
class Object {
  public:
    virtual Object* clone() { return new Object(); }
};

class SubObjectA {
  public:
    Object* clone() { return new SubObjectA(datablahblah); }
};

class SubObjectB {
  public:
    Object* clone() { return new SubObjectB(datablahblah); }
};

for (vector<Object*>::iterator it = objects.begin(); it != objects.end(); it++) {
    Object* tempobj = *it;
    old_objects.push_back(tempobj->clone());
}
```

But all I get is the same old:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Comment: what exactly have you tried till now ?

Comment: Which ways have you tried already?

Comment: For vector of pointers you should consider `Boost.PointerContainer`.

Comment: More important than what have you tried -- what has gone wrong?

Comment: "Object being a superclass for my level's objects" Well, there's your first problem. Any time you feel that `Object` is a suitable name for an object, you probably have a significant design problem.

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help you if you don't provide your code?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas In general, it is a good indicator, but when talking about a game world... they *are* objects that represent objects. There's a lot of elements shared between all game objects (position, scale, rotation, name). Any other name, like Entity, is just a technical sidestep.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Entity is probably a better name but it really doesn't change the problem.

Comment: @peachykeen: And that might work, right up until you have an "Object" which doesn't represent a physical object on the screen. Like an ObjectSpawnPoint, or just a collision box that you use to say when an Object has entered an area so you can run a script on it. At that point, "Entity" is a better term, because it is more nebulous about the concept of a physical representation. Objects are real things; Entities can be ethereal.

Comment: @ZachHinchy: "It throws out of range errors." On what index? Have you tried running it in a debugger? You are using a debugger, right? If not, you should learn how before doing any form of game development (or even semi-serious programming).

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I use GDB. However, I get to the part where normally it'd throw the out of range exception, and it just stalls infinitely. The vector range error is only printed to the console when I'm not running the debugger. I really have no idea why.

Comment: ...so I reinstalled GDB and now it does not stall at the out of range exception. It turns out that the out of range error was a completely unrelated error this entire time and my checkpoint code already was perfectly functional. FML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Prototype pattern and have your Object base class declare a pure virtual clone() method. Then at checkpoint time you just have to iterate over the vector calling clone on the pointers and pushing them into the new vector.

Comment: Added even more information to the post pertaining to your answer.

Comment: The edited code looks good. Ate you correctly initializing old_objects? It's hard to do it wrong but everything else looks fine. Is this program running in a single thread? If there is another thread running then maybe it's modifying the objects vector while you're iterating over it.

Comment: It turns out it was a completely unrelated error (GDB was screwing up but I reinstalled), and my code was fine. Thanks for reaffirming that though!

Answer (score 0):

The only important requirement here is to provide a deep copy constructor that stores all necessary information (or if that's not possible, a method to get all the required info). Then use that ctor/method to create a second vector. Something like:

```
class Object
{
    RenderObject * m_Renderable;
    int m_Health;
    float3 m_Position;

    Object(const Object * other) :
       m_Renderable(nullptr),
       m_Health(other->m_Health), 
       m_Position(other->m_Position)
    { };

    Object * GetStorable()
    {
        return new Object(*this);
    }
};
```

then to store "checkpoints", you simply do:

```
vector<vector<shared_ptr<Object>>> gCheckpoints;
vector<shared_ptr<Object>> gLevelObjects;

vector<shared_ptr<Object>> checkpoint;
std::for_each(
    gLevelObjects.begin(), gLevelObjects.end(),
    [&](shared_ptr<Object> obj)
    {
        checkpoint.push_back(obj->GetStorable());
    });
gCheckpoints.push_back(checkpoint); // creates a new checkpoint
```

You will need to recreate the render information for the objects when the checkpoint is restored; this is a requirement for most save systems in most graphics contexts, however.

Depending on how your `Object` class is set up, you can also inherit from another class that consists *only* of the stored data, and simply store that and create the renderables from it when necessary (`class RenderObject : StoredObject { ... };`).

You can alternatively serialize the objects in some fashion (binary save, xml, json) and store that to a file (autosave/quicksave/checkpoint) or in-memory, and then use your regular loading mechanism to load that specific file.

The best method depends on what your plans are and how your system is set up, but this concept should provide the basics or give you a starting point.

Comment: Lambda isn't supported before C++11. There may be a `boost.lambda` solution, though.

Comment: @moshbear Lambdas are much easier to write into an answer without cluttering it up. ;) If not using 11, then it can be replaced with a functor.

Comment: Seconded about easier to write. `Boost.bind` looks and feels like a hack.